# Improve String Comparison Time For Numpy Array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Is there a faster way to get a Boolean array from string comparison than the following, all the strings in the array are unique:

```
myArray = np.random.rand(500000).astype('S18')
toCompare = '0.166618892171'

%timeit np.in1d(myArray, toCompare)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.62 ms per loop

%timeit myArray == toCompare 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.86 ms per loop
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: No. What are you doing? Maybe there is a faster way to do what you are doing...

Comment: In short trying to access specific cells in a dataframe.

Comment: ok... you should ask that as the question (At the moment this is classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :) ) The answer I think will depend on the data, are all the strings different or do many of them share the same value?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The bigger picture I am trying to solve will take a very long to explain and its pretty convoluted. All the strings are unique

Comment: If all strings are unique then there's not going to be a faster way, all strings need to be compared. There could be a solution where you don't have to compare strings like that, or you could set this column as the index (not 100% if that makes a difference, but I would guess so).

Comment: Yup, it'll be at least a couple of orders of magnitude faster if you do that (O(1) vs O(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify my comments.

1. String comparison is never going to be faster than string comparison.
2. If you are looking up many different strings, (and using pandas) then it may make sense to use these strings as an Index*.

**An index uses klib hashtables under the hood so look up is O(1), whereas comparison is O(n).*

```
In [11]: a = np.random.rand(50000).astype('S18')

In [12]: %timeit a[a == a[0]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 971 µs per lo
```

Depending on what you want you could use `loc` or `get_loc`:

```
In [13]: ind = pd.Index(a)

In [14]: ind.get_loc(a[0])
Out[14]: 0
```

and from this you could get the mask (though most likely you just want this index!)

Note: This is time-stable:

```
In [15]: %timeit ind.get_loc(a[0])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.87 µs per loop

In [16]: %timeit ind.get_loc(a[-1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.04 µs per loop
```

There is a time and space-penalty here (to build the hash-table!), but it's a one-time construction cost. The performance ought to be even starker as the arrays get larger.

---

If there strings are not unique, then get_loc may return a mask!!

```
In [17]: ind.is_unique
Out[17]: True
```

Let's see this:

```
In [21]: a[-1] = a[0]

In [22]: ind = pd.Index(a)

In [23]: ind.get_loc(a[0])
Out[23]: array([ True, False, False, ..., False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [14]: ind.get_loc(a[1])  # but only for non-unique values
Out[14]: 1
```

---

If there are *many* strings which share the same value, you may benefit from using a [pandas Categorical object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)...

Comment: Note: my timings are a bit cheeky as they don't include the Index construction timing (which is O(n)... however, as mentioned, this is a one-time cost).